# Highcharts Add text to label

Tags: highcharts

Here is my chart : www.jsfiddle.net/bs9cLff5

I want to add the percent directly on the chart.
Example for team1 : I want to show 100% on the green.

Next, I would like to personalize the text in the label.

Team1
Good 100%

Become

Team1
'My text'

Is it possible?

Someone can help me please
Thank you everybody :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) to add custom elements (like text) in the chart.

```
chart.renderer.text('any text', 140, 140)
        .css({
            color: '#4572A7',
            fontSize: '16px'
        })
        .add();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can add to the previous answer, you can even define on click events for the label. It's very simple.

```
              ren.label('message', 10, 10)
                    .attr({
                      fill: 'red',
                      stroke: 'white',
                      'stroke-width': 2,
                      padding: 5,
                      cursor: 'pointer',
                      r: 5
                    })
                    .css({
                      color: 'white',
                      width: '100px'
                    })
                    // action on click
                    .on('click', function () {
                    });
```